# Clear cookies for xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin form and working on iOS application. I have also build the android application where i have used code like below for clear the cookies. How i can write this code iOS. If any body have any idea please covert the below like of code into iOS code. Thank you.

> Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookies(null)

Comment: Check out the iOS part of this [forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41039/setting-cookies-in-a-webview). Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSHttpCookieStorage CookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;

        foreach (var cookie in CookieStorage.Cookies)
        {
            CookieStorage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
        }
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: This doesn't work, I've used the code from @Bloodred566 to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recent iOS:

```
public void Clear()
    {
        NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.RemoveCookiesSinceDate(NSDate.DistantPast);

        WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.FetchDataRecordsOfTypes(WKWebsiteDataStore.AllWebsiteDataTypes, (NSArray records) => {

        for (nuint i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
        {
                var record = records.GetItem<WKWebsiteDataRecord>(i);
                WKWebsiteDataRecord[] recordArray = new WKWebsiteDataRecord[record.DataTypes.Count];
                WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.RemoveDataOfTypes(record.DataTypes, NSDate.DistantPast, ()=> { });
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I've been stuck with a cookie clearing issue in Xamarin Forms iOS for ages and your code fixed it. I was using the standard approach seen in the other answer but that's never worked.